# Looping properties of recursive chains of a special type of boundary of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let's define the operation b as b(X) = cl(X) - X. In other words, b(x) consists of all the points that are limit points of X, but are not elements of X. (There is probably a word for this but I couldn't find out what it's called, sorry.)
I'm interested what happens if you apply this recursively i.e. X<sub>n+1</sub> = b(X<sub>n</sub>).
This can either lead to some kind of loop or not. There always exists at least one possible loop, which is the empty set, and many sets will eventually arrive at the empty set, where the chain will loop. But under which circumstances can there be a chain that never loops?

If this problem is too general to have a good answer, an answer for the special case of the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$<sup>n</sup> would be satisfactory.
Here, $\mathbb{Q}$ leads to a loop of period 2. But I can't think of a chain that never loops.

Comment: b$^n$(R) is empty for all n > 0.  It does not loop but ends in a loop.

Comment: If it ends in a loop, then the sequence loops. I am interested in a chain that never loops.

Comment: A dense and co-dense set cycles, like the rationals and the irrationals. If we start with an open set, $b(O)$ is closed and nowhere dense so a fix point of $b$. Ditto with closed sets.

Comment: Cannot prove it yet, but I don't think there'll be any infinite sequence that never repeats.

Comment: I also suspect that in the special case there are no such chains. But the general case does have non-looping chains. Consider the infinite-dimensional space (R^inf). Any point is defined by countably infinite ordered real numbers, which correspond to the coordinates in the nth dimension. Let X be a set such that a point belongs to X iff there is an n so that the first 2n coordinates != 0 and the 2n+1th coordinate = 0. b(X) is (almost) self-similar but not identical.

Comment: Actually, "self-similar" is not quite right. What I meant is that b(X) looks almost like X with an additional coordinate of value 0 at the beginning of every point that belongs to it. And it's "almost" because the point (0,0,0,0,...) is not an element of X but is an element of b(X).